# sed remove only lines that are, but not lines containing

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a file with lots of lines that look much like this for simplification purposes.

```
aaaxxx
xxxbbb
xxx
aaaxxxbbb
bbbxxxaaa
aaa
bbb
```

Every time I try to come up with a sed command that filters out only the line with "xxx" all the other lines get filtered somehow. Maybe I'm using sed wrong, or there is another command for doing this.

The idea would be a sed command for deleting only lines that are xxx, but not lines containing xxx.

I can write a command that will delete the xxx line from the cli, but I need to do it repeatedly on demand in a script that takes an input variable from the user.

here is my latest 'not working' version:

```
read var
sed -i -e '/^$var$/d'
```

Comment: `$var` won't be expanded because it is inside a single-quoted string. Use double quotes. But if your target string could contain regular expression characters (`*+()[]{}?`), check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to remove all lines from a file which exactly match a given string, you can use grep:

```
 grep -vFx "$match" "$file"
```

The grep options:

```
-v  Invert the match. Print lines which don't match.
-F  The match is an exact string, not a regular expression
-x  The match must match an entire line (except for the newline)
```

Example:

```
$ cat file
aaaxxx
xxxbbb
xxx
aaaxxxbbb
bbbxxxaaa
aaa
bbb
$ match=xxx
$ grep -vFx "$match" file
aaaxxx
xxxbbb
aaaxxxbbb
bbbxxxaaa
aaa
bbb
```

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion awk is a better solution than sed or grep, because it can treat the pattern as a string, and not a regex.

```
awk -v x="$var" '$0!=x' file
```

Comment: grep can treat the pattern as a string. That's precisely the point of the -F option (which is Posix standard). On most systems, you can use `fgrep` but that's deprecated these days in favour of the -F option.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed '/^xxx$/d' File
```

or

```
sed -i.bak '/^xxx$/d' File   => this edits the file in place, keeping a backup.
```

Deletes only lines containg exactly `xxx` (`^ => beginning of line`, `$ => end of line`)

**Sample:**

```
AMD$ cat File
aaaxxx
xxxbbb
xxx
aaaxxxbbb
bbbxxxaaa
aaa
bbb

AMD$ sed '/^xxx$/d' File
aaaxxx
xxxbbb
aaaxxxbbb
bbbxxxaaa
aaa
bbb
```

**EDIT:**
If using a variable, use this:

```
read var
sed -i "/^$var$/d" File
```

Comment: For some reason this words in the cli, but doesn't work in a bin/bash scrip when feeding in a variable for xxx